# Starting JVM REST service, what is the stack should I use?

Tags: java, architecture, restful-architecture

If starting from scratch, with only requirements of JVM and existing MySQL database of medium complexity, and with the goal of doing only REST, nothing else, what is a good example of components I should use?

Want to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I guess here you would not find a single right answer but various opinions. For example, I would say that go with Spring Boot. It will be simple, elegant, less code and quick. And would meet all your requirements I guess.

Comment: @Siddharth Spring Boot does REST parsing?

Comment: absolutely, it does have.

Answer (score 1):

A few simple options can be:

[Spark Framework](http://sparkjava.com/), Sinatra-inspired + uses nice Java 8 features. Quick start example:

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

[Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), a simple way to start in Spring ecosystem. Quick start:

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring has Spring MVC module for building RETSful APIs, here's an example: http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

You can also take a look at other JVM languages, for example [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/) in Scala or [Grails](https://grails.org/) in Groovy.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention [Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/). It uses JAX-RS for RESTful APIs, which can look very verbose, but it's very mature and stable. Here's quick start guide: http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html